# Difference between SaaS App & Web App

Tags: web-applications, saas

Anybody, please explain the differences between a SaaS App and Web App. Also how can we make a Java Web App, a SaaS App?

Answer (score 5):

For me Saas (Software as a Service) is when you provide your application without any infrastructure requirement from the client, so the client could use your software without take care about the systems that support your software. A web app is a Saas application if the application runs in the provider infrastructure.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer, a web application can be provisioned as a software service (SaaS).

I suggest reading the series of [Wisdom of the Clouds](http://news.cnet.com/wisdom-of-clouds/) to get a in-depth and time-wise developments through time on the evolution of IaaS, SaaS, and PaaS.

Answer (score 2):

SaaS is about meeting criterion set by NIST. To convert a Java Web App to a SaaS, you need to change the backend and coding to make it scalable, flexible, redundant, multi-tenant. You can use Kubernetes, microservices, add load-balancers and a fail-proof DNS.

A web app is an application which can be accessed through a browser. WordPress running on a shared server modified to work as an application is also a web app. As individual developers, we usually develop a web app or traditional software.

A SaaS need to meet the criterion of cloud computing. That is technically difficult and costly for ordinary usage. Adobe Photoshop CC is a SaaS. Because it fulfils the criterion such as scalability, accessibility, persistence, on-demand computing power etc. Netflix is another example of SaaS.

To make a particular WordPress installation a SaaS, we need to fulfil the criterion set by NIST such scalability, availability, service continuity etc. Converting a web app or traditional software to SaaS demands to judge whether inviting such complexity worth. This answer is a [summary from my blog article](https://thecustomizewindows.com/2019/04/what-is-the-difference-between-a-web-application-and-a-saas-application/) to explain to you the basic.

Answer (score 0):

Often Web application and Saas terms will overlap. One of the main differences between a web app and SaaS is the system installation version. Saas provider will also have the system installable(applications developed for windows, mac OS etc.,) version which can be installed in customers's computer. A web app can be hosted any where. You can either host it locally or on the cloud but a SaaS should be hosted in the cloud.As abhishek ghosh explained in this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/61782257/8988448), A web application should meet criterion set by NIST.

Answer (score -1):

The SaaS model implies delivering digital products to users via an internet connection for a monthly fee. Since the software providers host these products, users do not have to install the software on their local computers.

[SaaS application development](https://syndicode.com/blog/how-to-develop-software-as-a-service/) has its peculiarities due to the cloud-based nature of SaaS apps, so it’s essential to follow six steps to build a successful product: planning, a discovery phase, application design, architecture design, development, and testing, maintenance, and further development.

A web application is a software or a program stored on a remote server and accessed via web browsers.
When a supplier gives you access to a cloud platform, one of the interfaces might be a web application. Web apps have the typical front-end and back-end web development technologies. In theory, web apps are closely related to websites.

So if you sum everything up, SaaS is a more specific concept for software licensing and delivery. A web application is a general term for any application you can access through a web interface.